# Normal Rotation in GLSL

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation, glsl, normals

I have written a basic program that loads a model and renders it to the screen. I'm using GLSL to transform the model appropriately, but the normals always seem to be incorrect after rotating them with every combination of model matrix, view matrix, inverse, transpose, etc that I could think of. The model matrix is just a rotation around the y-axis using glm:

```
angle += deltaTime;
modelMat = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), angle, glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
```

My current vertex shader code (I've modified the normal line many many times):

```
#version 150 core
uniform mat4 projMat;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform mat4 modelMat;
in vec3 inPosition;
in vec3 inNormal;
out vec3 passColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projMat * viewMat * modelMat * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    vec3 normal = normalize(mat3(inverse(modelMat)) * inNormal);
    passColor = normal;
}
```

And my fragment shader:

```
#version 150 core
in vec3 passColor;
out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(passColor, 1.0);
}
```

I know for sure that the uniform variables are being passed to the shader properly, as the model itself gets transformed properly, and the initial normals are correct if I do calculations such as directional lighting.

I've created a GIF of the rotating model, sorry about the low quality:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvEs9.gif

What confuses me the most is how the normals appear to rotate on multiple axis, which I don't think should happen when multiplied by a simple rotation matrix on one axis.

**Edit:**

I've added some more of the client code below.

This is where the buffers get bound for the model, in the `Mesh` class (`vao` is `GLuint`, defined in the class):

```
GLuint vbo[3];

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(normals? (uvcoords? 3 : 2) : (uvcoords? 2 : 1), vbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vcount * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

if(normals)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vcount * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
}

if(uvcoords)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vcount * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), uvcoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
}

glBindVertexArray(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &ib);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, icount * sizeof(GLushort), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

This is where the shaders are compiled after being loaded into memory with a simple readf(), in the `Material` class:

```
u32 vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
u32 fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&vsContent, 0);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
if(!validateShader(vertexShader)) return false;
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&fsContent, 0);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
if(!validateShader(fragmentShader)) return false;

programHandle = glCreateProgram();

glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShader);

glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "inPosition");
glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "inNormal");
//glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 2, "inUVCoords");

glLinkProgram(programHandle);
if(!validateProgram()) return false;
```

And the `validateShader(GLuint)` and `validateProgram()` functions:

```
bool Material::validateShader(GLuint shaderHandle)
{
    char buffer[2048];
    memset(buffer, 0, 2048);
    GLsizei len = 0;

    glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle, 2048, &len, buffer);
    if(len > 0)
    {
        Logger::log("ve::Material::validateShader: Failed to compile shader - %s", buffer);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Material::validateProgram()
{
    char buffer[2048];
    memset(buffer, 0, 2048);
    GLsizei len = 0;

    glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, 2048, &len, buffer);
    if(len > 0)
    {
        Logger::log("ve::Material::validateProgram: Failed to link program - %s", buffer);
        return false;
    }

    glValidateProgram(programHandle);
    GLint status;
    glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
    if(status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        Logger::log("ve::Material::validateProgram: Failed to validate program");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Each `Material` instance has a `std::map` of `Mesh`s, and get rendered as so:

```
void Material::render()
{
    if(loaded)
    {
        glUseProgram(programHandle);

        for(auto it = mmd->uniforms.begin(); it != mmd->uniforms.end(); ++it)
        {
            GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, (const GLchar*)it->first);

            switch(it->second.type)
            {
            case E_UT_FLOAT3: glUniform3fv(loc, 1, it->second.f32ptr); break;
            case E_UT_MAT4: glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, it->second.f32ptr); break;
            default: break;
            }
        }

        for(Mesh* m : mmd->objects)
        {
            GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "modelMat");
            glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m->getTransform()->getTransformMatrix()[0][0]);
            m->render();
        }
    }
}
```

`it->second.f32ptr` would be a `float` pointer to `&some_vec3[0]` or `&some_mat4[0][0]`.
I manually upload the model's transformation matrix before rendering, however (which is only a rotation matrix, the `Transform` class (returned by Mesh::getTransform()) will only do a glm::rotation() since I was trying to figure out the problem).

Lastly, the `Mesh` render code:

```
if(loaded)
{
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

I think this is all the necessary code, but I can post more if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if the vertex normals of a mesh are incorrect, then strange rotation artifacts will occur. In my case, I had transformed the mesh in my 3D modelling program (Blender) by 90 degrees on the X axis, as Blender uses the z-axis as its vertical axis, whereas my program uses the y-axis as the vertical axis. However, the method I used to transform/rotate the mesh in Blender in my export script did not properly transform the normals, but only the positions of the vertices. Without any prior transformations, the program works as expected. I initially found out that the normals were incorrect by comparing the normalized positions and normals in a symmetrical object (I used a cube with smoothed normals), and saw that the normals were rotated. Thank you to @derhass and @Solkar for guiding me to the answer.

However, if anyone still wants to contribute, I would like to know why the normals don't rotate in one axis when multiplied by a single axis rotation matrix, even if they are incorrect.

Comment: Something I'll add to this. I use Blender and export to GLTF. I've found my life is made extremely easy if I simply always model in Blender with Z as my 'up' axis, and then transform to Y=up in the export menu. That way things always face the right direction in both Z-up and Y-up systems.

Answer (score 3):

Your nomal matrix calculation is just wrong. The correct normal matrix would be the transpose of the inverse of the upper-left 3x3 submatrix of the model or modelview matrix (depending on which space you want to do your lighting calculations).

What you do is just inverting the full 4x4 matrix and taking the upper-left 3x3 submatrix of that, which is just totally wrong.

You should calculate `transpose(inverse(mat3(modelMat)))`, but you really shouldn't do this in the shader, but calulate this toghether with the model matrix on the CPU to avoid letting  the GPU calculate a quite expensive matrix inversion *per vertex*.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but I'm still at a loss. I changed the normal line to
`vec3 normal = normalize(transpose(inverse(mat3(modelMat))) * inNormal);`
but still have similar results with incorrect normals

Comment: @user3764686: Well, what space do you want your normals in? That is not really clear from your question. It is also unclear if your input normals are correct. And you also have to renormalize them in the FS, as the linear interpolation does not preserve the length.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have set the output color equal to the normals to determine if they are rotating correctly, but the animated image in the main question illustrates what happens. I don't know if this is correct, but I think that the colors (normal values) shouldn't be moving vertically around the sphere, despite if I use model space or view space.

Comment: Also, even if my normals are initially incorrect, shouldn't they still just rotate uniformly around the y-axis due to the rotation matrix? Also I am normalizing the normals after the multiplication. Sorry if my assumptions are incorrect, and please tell me if I'm still being unclear. For now, I guess I'll just say I want the normals in model space (the view matrix is constant for now, by the way). Thank you. 

(Original message was too long for a single comment)

Comment: @user3764686: Even if your view matrix is constant, it might still contain some rotation which _might_ cause the effect you are seeing. But I'm not really sure. You at least should see a different behavior between the original image and the one for the formula I gave. As for the renormalization: you normalize after the multiplication (as you should), but you don't renormalize them in the fragment shader (which you also should do, because they aren't going to stay normalized during the interpolation).

Comment: I've moved the mat3() call around, and it appears to be exactly the same, which seems very odd to me since the shader code is definitely being executed. And I thought normals were just extra data passed to the shader, and not necessarily passed to the fragment shader unless programmed to do so. Should I create a normal variable in the fragment shader to be passed from the vertex shader? And how would I specify that they should be output as normals? Also I'm using `viewMat*modelMat` now, but it still looks the same. The fact that moving mat3() around didn't change anything is really confusing..

Comment: @user3764686: It's not only the place where the mat3() conversion occurs, but also the additional transpose. You are already passing your normals to the FS (as `passColor`). But it is really unclear what is going on, it would be helpful to see more of your client code, not just the shaders.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was just passing the normals as colors to see if they rotated properly, because I was noticing that my directional lighting algorithm was moving in weird directions. That line of code was originally `passColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * dot(normal, -lightDir);`, where lightDir was passed as uniform. I will upload some more client code on the main question now.

Comment: I've uploaded the necessary client code to the main question.

Comment: @user3764686: The code posted so far looks OK to me, at first glance. One thing: VAOs also troe the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding, so you actually can bind this once when the VAO is bound, and don't need to re-bind it at every draw call. But that is just a tiny performance improvement, not a matter of correctness.

Comment: @user3764686: I thought a bit more about the image you posted. I'm not really sure here, but I think the the impression of the vertical movement _might_ just be an artifact of the fact that half of your value range is clamped. Can you try to visualize the normals using `outColor = vec4(passColor, 1.0) * 0.5 + vec4(0.5);` to map the range [-1,1] to [0,1]?

Comment: The colors/normals still have that vertical movement, it just made the sphere lighter due to the remapping. Is there a certain type of matrix that would cause the normals to spin in this fashion? I just can't imagine why the normals don't rotate correctly if the mesh itself rotates properly.

Comment: That gif indicates deformed normals. For a smooth sphere, the vertex normals should be collinear to the vertex position in the local frame, so try to use the normalized vertex position as a substitute for the normals of the imported model.

Comment: @Solkar: Wow, that's a very smart idea. I did that by replacing `inNormal` with `normalize(inPosition)`, and it works as intended. But why do the normals move in strange directions if they're not initially correct? I would've expected to still see some sort of uniform rotation in either case. I'll investigate the normals output from my 3D modelling program, but they seemed correct after printing out the loaded data in my program.

Comment: @user3764686: I already said that all bets are off if your input normals are wrong. You might confuse yourself by the fact that you visualize the directions as color.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean with "normals move in strange directions". If you turn the sphere the way you do, the assignment of color to vertex remains invariant; thus you see all rainbow colors + shades of grey,  as it is the case. The only real issue is the bumps, and that obviously is caused by bad incoming normal data.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your transformations consist of only rotations, translations, and uniform scaling, you can simply apply the rotation part of your transformations to the normals.

In general, it's the transposed inverse matrix that needs to be applied to the normals, using only the regular 3x3 linear transformation matrix, without the translation part that extends the matrix to 4x4.

For rotations and uniform scaling, the inverse-transpose is identical to the original matrix. So the matrix operations to invert and transpose matrices are only needed if you apply other types of transformations, like non-uniform scaling, or shear transforms.